# terraform.tfvars file not found when running GitHub action

Tags: terraform

I have created my terraform.tfvars file as such recommended. Terraform supposedly automatically finds it.

**terraform.tfvars**

```
var1 = "a123"
var2 = "a123"
var3 = "a123"
var4 = "a123"
```

I set up my GitHub Workflow action as follows:

```
name: Terraform

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1

      - name: Install Azure CLI
        run: curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash 

      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS}}

      - name: Terraform Init
        run: terraform init

      - name: Terraform Plan
        run: terraform plan

      - name: Terraform Apply
        run: |
          terraform apply --auto-approve
```

This is the message I get:
[image]

What am I missing?

when I run locally `terraform apply` it works perfectly.

Comment: Have you committed the `terraform.tfvars` file to the repo?

Comment: @MarkoE Oh lord...I forgot I had the file extension (for a good reason) in my gitignore file. That did it. :)

Comment: It sounds like this question is effectively answered by the comments above. If so, it would help to summarize the answer as an actual answer and then mark that answer as accepted so that this will stop appearing as an "unanswered" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually specify the variable file after adding tfvars file to the repo and run this command `terraform plan --var-file = terraform.tfvars`.